# Why pseudo-elements :before and :after appear in front of my DIV element and not behind?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I have a DIV element with this given class:

```
.slideshow { background: white; width: 700px; height: 300px; padding:10px; margin: 0 auto; position: relative; box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px grey, 0px 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.1) inset; }
```

I define those two pseudo-elements (**:before** and **:after**):

```
.slideshow:before, .slideshow:after { content: " "; background: green; width: 50%; height: 50%; position: absolute; z-index: -10; }
```

My problem is that those two pseudo-elements appear in front of my DIV and not behind. Is there any specific reason for this behaviour?

Here is an example: [EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/XRVGD/)

The Javascript part is a bit messy but i'm still working on it.

Also I've noticed that if I delete all the JS part I don't have anymore this problem, but I don't think there is anything in the code that should modify the **slideshow** DIV.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Mf4M5/ I fiddled it.  Please modify it and update your question to be appropriate markup to help explain what the issue is.

Comment: Well, I've modified the fiddle you've created and it's working correctly. My problem is that on the site i'm doing the two pseudo-elements appear in front of the div element and not behind. It's like if the z-index property was set on 1.

Comment: Good to hear you've solved the issue! Would you be so kind and post your solution *as an answer*? If you answer your own question it'll be easier for future visitors to see.

Comment: Please do not mark title with "Solved".  Just post your solution as an answer below, and then "accept" it.

Comment: I can't answer my own question, I have to wait 6h because of my reputation...I'm still new here. I'll do it as soon as possible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED:** The problem is in the javascript part where I have:

```
$('.slideshow').css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(0deg)');
```

Removing this line solved my problem.

I guess that pseudo-elements **:before** and **:after** are not 100% compatible with the property **transform**.

Comment: It's not that. The `transform` property (including `z-index` and a few others) will establish a new stack context on your `.slideshow` element. And every child of that element will be placed above the stack context